# Select2js: catch keydown events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jquery-select2

For some reason, `select2js` seems to operate independently from the rest of my application as far as `keydown` events are concerned.

A simple example is preventing inputs:

```js
$(() => {

  $("#select2-div").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true,
    width: "75%",
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    dropdownParent: $("#select2-div").parent()
  })

  $(document).keydown((e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
  })


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items:center; width: 400px;">
  <select multiple id="select2-div">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
    <option value="maybe">Maybe</option>
    <option value="idontknow">I don't know</option>
  </select>
  
  <input style="margin-left: 30px; width: 100px"type="text">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the user still able to input things in the select2 input (but, rightly so, not in the standard input)? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The event is dispatched in two phases, the default phase is the second one, "bubbling", which sends the event first to the innermost child where `select2`'s listener is attached so it sees the event first, then the event bubbles up to `document` where your listener sees it.

The solution is to add a listener in the first event phase, "capturing", where the event descends (from `window` to `document` to `body` and down the DOM tree to the innermost element), by using the vanilla DOM `addEventListener` with the third parameter set to `true`. If you stop the event in a capturing listener, it won't be dispatched to the listeners in the next phase ("bubbling").

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // disables the browser's default behavior
  e.stopPropagation(); // disables the bubbling phase listeners
}, true);
```

Disabling an individual key pressed inside a specific element:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Escape' && e.target.closest('.select2-container')) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disables the browser's default behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // disables the bubbling phase listeners
  }
}, true);
```

You can also use `document` here, which is the second target in the capturing phase.

Some sites may need you to run your content script earlier by adding ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time) to its declaration. Note that when it runs there'll be no `document.body`, so if you also need DOM contents you'll wait for it like `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', someFunction)`